# JS Lint - Strict violation - defining function in a constructor object

Tags: javascript, oop, this, jslint

I am new to OOP JavaScript and just having a play when I am getting a Strict Violation in JSLint for the following

```
function HeaderNav(){
  this.activateMobile = function () {
     alert('activateMobile');
  }
}
```

the strict violation is on the line

```
this.activateMobile = function () {
```

I need the method activateMobile() to have "this." so it works when

```
var navigation = new HeaderNav();
navigation.activateMobile();
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because JSLint wants you to use `"use strict";` at the start of every function block? Try running JSLint with `--sloppy`.

Comment: thanks robert, but made no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
this.activateMobile = function () {};
```

the function is not part of the prototype, which means that a subclass of `HeaderNav` will not get this function (unless you do an explicit *super* call). Setting a property directly on `this` only sets that property for that *instance*

To add a function to a prototype do:

```
function HeaderNav() {} 
HeaderNav.prototype.activateMobile = function () {
  alert('activateMobile');
};
```